# How to nest formula into one formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two formula's to extract only the last name, and a formula to get the correct character in capital.

i.e:

```
input: de heer K.W. in 't Bosch
output: in 't Bosch
```

```
=RIGHT(D11;LEN(D11)-FIND("|";SUBSTITUTE(D11;".";"|";LEN(D11)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(D11;".";"")))))
```

The second formula gives:

```
input: de heer K.W. in 't Bosch
output: In 't Bosch  (as it should be).
```

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(PROPER(E8);" de ";" De ");" La ";" la ");" 'T ";" 't ") =
```

Is there any way to nest this in one formula?
I've been trying for an hour, and I can't figure out why I can't get it done.

Comment: Why not just use upper() and left() on the first character? Or proper()?

Comment: The proper won't work, as not all first characters of the surename should be a capital.

I could try the other option you've mentioned.
Thank you.

Is this also to transform it in VBA?

Comment: What version of Excel?

Comment: 365 (I think business or enterprise, as I use a device from work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you define "last name" as everything after the last dot (`.`)
So I would simplify the first formula to:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(`D11`,".",REPT(" ",99)),99))
```

Then, to combine, merely substitute that for `E8` in your second formula

```
 =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(PROPER(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",REPT(" ",99)),99)))," De "," de ")," La "," la ")," 'T "," 't ")
```

but I wonder if your `de=>De` is reversed? (***Edit** I just corrected that in my suggestion*)

***Note: my system uses the `comma` for the argument separator; you will need to change that to your `semicolon`***

In O365, if you have the `LET` function, perhaps a more understandable formula:

```
=LET(x,TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(D11,".",REPT(" ",99)),99)),
     y, UPPER(LEFT(x)),
     z, MID(x,2,99),
     y&z)
```

***Edit***
*Given the three examples you have mentioned, here is the output using either function, although with the "long" function I reverse "de" and "De" from what you show:*

[image]

Comment: These are the Dutch grammar rules when writing a letter. 
When ie.  dear mrs. J. de Graaf, it becomes dear mrs De Graaf.

When :
mrs J. van de Graaf, it becomes mrs Van de Graaf.

I couldn't find a specific rule or function to do this, so I have to do it manually.

I will try later this evening your aswer.
I'll let you know.

thank you.

Comment: @Amateur so you will have to either write separate functions for each of the rules and pick between them or one with it all built in. Must have missed that detail in your original post.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld: This works perfect! Thank you so much! I'm not yet familiar with the LET formula, but this is defintely something to dive in! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I tried combining both formulas and ended with this:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(PROPER(RIGHT(D11;LEN(D11)-FIND("|";SUBSTITUTE(D11;".";"|";LEN(D11)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(D11;".";""))))));" de ";" De ");" La ";" la ");" 'T ";" 't ")
```

Does it do any good?

Comment: Thank you for looking into it Dominique. Unfortunately I get an error.

Comment: Domnique, I was lying, I'm sorry. I forg0t to change the cells. This works as wel like a charm! Thank you so much!

Comment: I do have to make conditions manually though. I think Ron's solutions suits the situations just better.

Comment: @Amateur: I had created this formula by inserting one into the other. Apparently you were having some issues while trying to do this?

Comment: Yes, I coundn't, so I'm very grateful you guys helped me out!